# Programmatically connect to ASP.NET WebAPI sitting behind ForeFront UAG

Tags: xamarin.ios, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI built using ASP.NET MVC4.  It is a simple API for getting data (simple HTTP GET requests). The API is stable and has been working with our mobile (MonoTouch) app for quite some time.  Now we're putting ForeFront UAG in front of the API (simply changed web.config to use windows auth.  Testing the security and API through a browser e.g. Chrome, and the UAG login is presented (when hitting API first time).  Enter your credentials and then you get the data back for the API GET request.  All what you'd expect.  Now, from .NET code (no browser) I want to do the same thing.  I've seen examples accessing SharePoint programmatically and some windows phone stuff, but none of them seem to work for ASP.NET MVC4 WebApi calls from just regular old .NET code (which I'll eventually use in MonoTouch).

**Anyone have an example of how to Authenticate and then make HTTP GET request successfully through UAG to an ASP.NET MVC4 WebApi?**

Comment: Daron, id like to know if you managed to to get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the disposal over a ForeFront UAG so I can't test this. But in general you have a few options. The samples are snippets and some code is left out for readability.

**WebClient / HttpWebRquest**

```
CredentialCache credentials = new CredentialCache();
credentials.Add(new Uri(url), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain));

//WebClient
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Credentials = credentials;

//HttpWebRequest
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = credentials
```

**HttpClient**

```
WebRequestHandler clientHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
clientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
clientHandler.AllowPipelining = true;
clientHandler.ImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

ProgressMessageHandler progress = new ProgressMessageHandler();

httpClient = HttpClientFactory.Create(clientHandler, progress);
```

You have also the options of using third party libraries to get this job done, like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)  or [Service Stack](http://www.servicestack.net/). 
Personally I make use of RestSharp because of the ease of use and serializing/deserializing capabilities.